# Can I test a custom data flow SSIS component

Tags: c#, unit-testing, ssis

I have developed a custom SSIS data flow component. I am wondering if it possible to test my component? It outputs a file and I also populate the output pipeline.

Comment: If You are asking: "How can I test component without running BIDS and puting component into package dataflow?" then the answer is no. If You find one I would be more than happy to know! :)